# How to make a uniform margin for multiple components on a single view?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3, the same goes for vuetify. I have my app bar in the `App.vue`. I have a few `views` on which I am using I am using multiple components. The problem is attached in the screenshots in my question.

I want a proper way to align these components in a uniform margin with respect to the appbar in my entire project.

[image]

[image]

This is my `app.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-app class="container">
    <v-app-bar color="green" class="app-bar">
      <v-toolbar-title class="ml-0 pl-4">
        <span class="hidden-sm-and-down">{{ appName }}</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="gotoHome()">
        <h3>Dashboard</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">mdi-ballot</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="dialog = !dialog">
        <h3>Markets</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">mdi-apps</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="gotoSettings()">
        <h3>Settings</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">settings</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="gotoVerus()">
        <h3>Verus</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">mdi-apps</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" fullscreen hide-overlay transition="dialog-bottom-transition">
      <v-card>
        <v-toolbar>
          <v-btn dark @click="dialog = false">
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-toolbar-title>Markets</v-toolbar-title>
          <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
          <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn dark text @click="dialog = false">back</v-btn>
          </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-list three-line subheader>
          <v-subheader>Go to markets</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>Informational Section</v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>Please wait for the available market links to load</v-list-item-subtitle>
              <AppMarkets v-on:gotoMarket="gotoMarket" :key="componentKey" />
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        location="left"
        temporary
      >
        <v-list
          :items="items"
        ></v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to achieve properly this.

**Using flexbox**, you can set the app-header to be inside a column container, for example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-bar {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 44px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="app-bar">
    My app bar above content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    My content
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you use absolute position, you can **use margin** like this:

```css
html {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* added code before is only to erase code snippet behaviour */

.app-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
 
 .content {
  margin-top: 44px; /* increase it to simulate a gap */
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="app-bar">
    My app bar above content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    My content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work I have updated my question with the code for app.vue

Comment: It's because you use vuetify, try to create a working example online of your problem.
Or explain what doesn't work, and if you have added more css try to add it too.